# Custom Speech TTS samples return "HTTP/1.1 503 Synthesis failed. StatusCode: Unavailable, Details: Connect Failed"

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech

When trying to run the samples provided on the "Custom Speech" endpoint page, I've come across two issues.

1. When running it as provided, I get a `400 Bad Request` because the voice with name `Foo Bar` cannot be found. Replacing `<voice name="Foo Bar">` with `<voice>` in the SSML I send to the service resolved this so far.
2. Now I unfortunately get the following HTTP response (either in my browser's dev console when using the dialog on the Custom Speech website or via a manual HTTP call with my http client of choice):

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Synthesis failed. StatusCode: Unavailable, Details: Connect Failed.
Content-Type: text/xml
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 1FB8BE38F3034E6781319BEDB3570D5D Ref B: FRAEDGE1113 Ref C: 2019-12-11T11:43:41Z
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 11:43:43 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The C# nuget library throws no exceptions, it just returns a 0 bytes.

Is there anything I have to keep in mind when setting this up to get custom TTS or might the service have issues? We're running a S0 instance and setting up multiple deployment endpoints didn't help as well. All parts have "succeeded" according to the Speech Studio interface.

Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now that I got everything working, a quick follow up.

1. the first point regarding the HTTP request in my question was indeed a backend problem which was solved by Microsoft today.
2. However, point 2 was then still not fixed because of a problem in my code. I got 0 bytes because I set `speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName` to a standard voice name instead of my custom `Foo Bar` voice.

Answer (score 0):

sibbl

can you send email to Custom Voice Support email "customvoice @ microsoft.com"
we might ask you some details of your subscription to debug this issue

-
sheng

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will try this email after I only got a "this mailbox is unmonitored" reply pointing to Stack Overflow this morning following the "contact us" link in the Speech Studio. ;-)

Comment: you can also open an azure ticket